# Error while using CASE in WHERE clause in Oracle Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case, where-clause

This is my query and when I am running it, I am getting error "missing Keyword".
can anyone please help with it

```
SELECT COUNT(1)  
FROM ar_invoice_master,proposal,proposal_to_opportunity 
WHERE proposal.PROPOSAL_ID=proposal_to_opportunity.FK_PROPOSAL_ID 
AND proposal_to_opportunity.FK_AR_INVOICE_ID=ar_invoice_master.AR_INVOICE_ID 
AND  CASE 
        WHEN ar_invoice_master.FK_INVOICE_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('REN','TRS') THEN ar_invoice_master.AR_INVOICE_OS_AMOUNT>0  
        WHEN ar_invoice_master.FK_INVOICE_TYPE_CODE  IN ('REN','TRS') THEN (AR_INVOICE_OS_AMOUNT/AR_INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT * 100)<100
      END
AND proposal.FK_GLUSR_USR_ID=: glid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND..OR` instead of a `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
AND ((ar_invoice_master.FK_INVOICE_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('REN','TRS')
      AND ar_invoice_master.AR_INVOICE_OS_AMOUNT>0)
  OR (ar_invoice_master.FK_INVOICE_TYPE_CODE  IN ('REN','TRS')
      AND (AR_INVOICE_OS_AMOUNT/AR_INVOICE_TOTAL_AMOUNT * 100)<100))
```

The reason it doesn't work is that `CASE` is not a `statement` but an `expression`, it can't return a condition.

Comment: Thank you , i would take that suggestion